# Processing Submissions on arXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv, online-publication

My submission has been processing for two days now, is this normal? I know that submissions might get the tag [on hold] and take a long time, but arXiv says that if this does not happen, submissions tend to stay in the "processing" phase for a relatively short time. My question is whether two days classifies as a "relatively short time" and, if so, how long does a submission usually take to process? If it does not classify as a relatively short time, who should I go to to ask for help?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the time in processing status follows a roughly bimodal distribution. The first peak is when everything goes well, and certainly occurs before even a day has passed. The second, presumably broader, peak depends on how long it takes the automatic processing system to fail, and someone to have a look at it. I don't know where this second peak is located, but the point is that I expect there to be two "normals", depending on whether your submission had technical issues or not. Personally, I'd feel justified in [contacting arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) after three days or so.